# How to detect touch on drawing with UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext?

Tags: swift, uigraphicscontext

Here code draw line

```
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect)  {
        super.draw(rect)
        
        guard  let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }
        //Draw line
        lines.forEach { (line) in
            context.setStrokeColor(line.color.cgColor)
            context.setLineWidth(CGFloat(line.strokeWidth))
            context.setLineCap(.round)
            
            for (i, p) in line.point.enumerated() {
                if i == 0 {
                    context.move(to: p)
                } else {
                    context.addLine(to: p)
                }
            }
            context.strokePath()
        }
    }
```

How to detect which drawing I'm touching?
Example: I've 3 line freestyle red,yellow and blue when I touch on yellow line ,I'll erase it

This is my image

![1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaJi3.png

Comment: You have to save info about where the drawing is.

Comment: @matt Yup! I save it with model when the line is drawn

Comment: Then you know where the touch is, you know where the lines are, you can work out whether the touch is close to a line.

Comment: @matt Yup, thanks you. That is also my solution,but it's not true on some case.Example drawing freestyle and those lines overlap and draws have arrpoint contain point touch .

Comment: Hi Tiến. I see that you already have a partial solution, but that it doesn't work in all cases. If you could post the solution you have, and describe those cases, it would help us help you.Otherwise, I see two situations: a) when two lines overlap and b) if the touch falls in between the points making up your freestyle line. For "a", it's up to you to decide: do you want to claim both lines are touched, or just the "top" one? If the latter, then you should check each line in turn, starting with the last one drawn.